# MSSQL2014 Installation Issue

Tags: windows-10, sql-server, sql-server-2014

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Setup

The following error has occurred:

The process cannot access the file `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Sqlwep-uni-(96bf8744-d4b7-4205-920d-cf1b69b6ed88).mof` because it is being used by another process.

How can I discover which another process accessing this `.mof` file and stop it from accessing this `.mof` file. So that I can properly install MSSQL 2014 on my PC.

Additional Info: I have installed Kaspersky antivirus installed.

Comment: Possibly some other MSI installer is running, maybe an update or something.  If you can't reboot this system, try killing any `msiexec.exe` processes not owned by `SYSTEM`.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. i solved it by running setup.exe by super user(Run as Administrator).